# Error when trying to format excel cells to scientific number format, C#

Tags: c#, numbers, format, export-to-excel

I am trying to format a cell range to scientific number formats.
Below are my C# codes.

```
excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
// for making Excel visible
excel.Visible = true;
excel.DisplayAlerts = true;
excelworkBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
excelSheet =     (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelworkBook.ActiveSheet;
excelSheet.Name = "Mean Shift and Sigma Ratio";
excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[4, 2], excelSheet.Cells[4, Analysisdt.Rows.Count + 1]].NumberFormat = "{0:E2}";
```

When the line that format the cells for "{0:E2}" it complained the following:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Dynamic.dll

Additional information: Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class

Is the format code in error? I could not find any MSDN references, and found some body post the "{0:E2}" for scientific number formatting.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the issue is that the data within that range is mixed formats.  So you can't specify one format across an entire range.

Comment: I think the format you're looking for is `"0.00E+00"`

Comment: The "0.00E+00" format works. Thanks S O.